Trying to add request and response headers to backend created using the hapxory dataplane api
I've been trying to add a response header and a request header to a backend entry. I'm using the haproxy dataplane api in NodeJs. The backend is successfully created but what I think are the appropriate calls to add headers do not work. Specifically the response header addition.
The two headers I would like to add are:
 http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
 http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *"

My current understanding is that there is not a way to give optional headers to the endpoint that creates the backend. Instead you have to manually add them in separate calls, one to add request headers and one to add response headers.
So, I've created two nodejs js calls that take these as options:
let configRequest={
  "type": "set-header",
  "index": 0,
  "hdr_name": "X-Client-IP",
  "hdr_format": "%[src]"
};

You then call the endpoint: /services/haproxy/configuration/http_request_rules
As per: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#post-/services/haproxy/configuration/http_request_rules
That one appears to work. The options for the response seems to be something like:
let configResponse={
  "type": "set-header",
  "cond": "if",
  "cond_test": "???",
  "index": 0,
  "hdr_name": "Content-Security-Policy",
  "hdr_format": "frame-ancestors *"
};

Which is POST submitted to the endpoint: /services/haproxy/configuration/http_response_rules
As per: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#post-/services/haproxy/configuration/http_response_rules
Where do I stick the value "frame-ancestors *" for the hdr_name value? Assuming that's how this is supposed to work.
I'm completely guessing here since the documentation is uhmmm not so clear. Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

After working on this for a few days I ended up with a call that works. I can see this work as an example for other generic header adds, so I provide it here for anyone stuck in a similar situation. The config object to the call I use is:
let configResponse={
  "type": "set-header",
  "index": 0,
  "hdr_name": "Content-Security-Policy",
  "hdr_format": "\"frame-ancestors *\"",
  "hdr_match": "*"
};

This produces the following haproxy config line in the backend section:
http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *"

